# How to clear ONLY app_webview cache with cordova plugin cache?

Tags: cordova, local-storage

i'm trying to delete cache from app_webview with window.cache.clear(); from cordova.plugin.cache.www https://github.com/moderna/cordova-plugin-cache.

But with this command deletes "Local Storage" folder too which i need.
Is there any way to clear only the Cache folder, not the Local Storage folder.